# connect to android device via usb

Tags: android, usb

Is there an API or another way to access an android device's data (contacts, gallery, messages) while being connected via USB ? Can it be done using java or .net framework ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can either use:
1. ADB commands to view and pull the device data.
2. Connect the device in USB Connected mode and access it from your PC. 
   Procedure : Drag a screen from the top in your home screen- Select usb connected mode- Turn on usb storage- then access.

Comment: Thanks ! if i would go for the second option, could i have access to contacts and messages ?

Comment: No. You can view the contents of the sdcard only . To view the contacts there exists an api refer http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/contacts.html and for accessing the messages refer to content provider data or http://groups.google.com/group/android-beginners/browse_thread/thread/2e049e79f88d95d5?pli=1